# How to render grid with ReactJs and Materialize?

Tags: reactjs, materialize

What would be the best way to render a grid using `Materialize css` framework and `ReactJs`?

Do I create a skeleton to index.html and then render there? Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6"></div>
    <div class="col s6"></div>
</div
```

How would I tell ReactJs that I want to render in the second `col s6` element?
Because if I do `ReactDom.Render(</Element>, document.getElementById("col s6"))`, it will probably take the first one?

What if I wanted to render to both elements? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use ReactJs, but you are currently trying to get elements by `id` who have no `id`. You can select both elements with the [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method:

```
var containers = document.getElementsByClassName("col s6");
```

Now considering only your shown HTML `containers` will be a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) with the two elements. ReactJs could probably then be used as follows:

```
ReactDom.Render(</Element>, containers[0])
ReactDom.Render(</Element>, containers[1])
```

Another option would be to add the `id` attribute to the `div` in order to keep using the [`getElementsById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col s6"></div>
    <div id="col2" class="col s6"></div>
</div

/* JavaScript */
ReactDom.Render(</Element>, document.getElementById("col1"))
ReactDom.Render(</Element>, document.getElementById("col2))
```